# Java Resource Access in JAR

Tags: java, maven, jar, resources

I am trying to access resources inside the jar that also contains my classes.

There are some questions on this site that show how to, but not one of them works.

My code is this:

```
package nl.joshuaslik.UFMReckoning;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getFile("file/test.txt"));
    }

    private static String getFile(String fileName) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");

        // Get file from resources folder
        ClassLoader classLoader = App.class.getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
        System.out.println(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getPath());

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                result.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result.toString();
    }

}
```

And my directory layout is this:

```
classes
├── nl
|   └── joshuaslik
|       └── UFMReckoning
|           └── App.class
└── file
    └── test.txt
```

This code runs fine while not in a jar.

[image: Outside JAR]

However, it will not work while inside a jar.

```
UFM-Reckoning-0.0.0-alpha.0.jar
├── nl
|   └── joshuaslik
|       └── UFMReckoning
|           └── App.class
├── META-INF
|   └── MANIFEST.MF
└── file
    └── test.txt
```

[image: Inside JAR]

It is visible that the file that it is trying to access is: `file:/D:/Joshua/Git/Coding/UFM-Reckoning/build/UFM-Reckoning-0.0.0-alpha.0.jar!/file/test.txt`, which seems like a strange path to me, because of the `!` in it, which is not allowed on Windows.

Contents of MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: Joshua
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.3
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_25
Main-Class: nl.joshuaslik.UFMReckoning.App
```

Does anybody know how it can be fixed?

I am using Windows 7 64-bit and Maven to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried classloader.getResourceAsStream() method?

Comment: I don't know why the getResourceAsStream() wouldn't work the previous time, but it does now. However, this method wouldn't work for images right? So then the same problem occurs that the file would not be found.

Comment: getResource() in your example isn't the same as getResourceAsStream()